# Sending messages between servers using patchbay

Tags: java, oracle, atg

I'm currently working on an application that would monitor specific jobs and services that are running on a website. I'm currently using patch bay to send messages and receive them in defined message sources and sinks. This all works when it is running on one server, however when trying to send a message from the publishing server to the production server, it never gets received however I can see through debugging that it at least gets as far as the send message function. I know I have set patchbay up correctly as I am receiving it on one server.

Does anyone have any idea how you can send messages between servers in Oracle ATG (using patchbay, or if there is another way, that would be good as well).

The following code is a rough idea of how I'm currently doing it:

**Message Source(MessageChannel):**

```
public void dispatchAlert()
{
alert = "Hello world"    
msg = getMessageSourceContext().createObjectMessage("Port");
msg.setObject(alert);
messageSourceContext.sendMessage("Port", msg);
}
```

**Message Sink(Broker):**

```
public void recieveMessage(String status, Message msg)
{
logInfo("Received message: " + msg);
}
```

**Patchbay**:

```
    <message-source>
        <nucleus-name>
            /com/MessageChannel
        </nucleus-name>
        <output-port>
            <port-name>Port</port-name>
            <output-destination>
                <destination-name>
                    patchbay:/sqldms/com/SystemBroker
                </destination-name>
                <destination-type>Topic</destination-type>
            </output-destination>
        </output-port>
    </message-source>

<message-sink>
        <nucleus-name>
            /com/Broker
        </nucleus-name>
        <input-port>
            <port-name>Port</port-name>
            <input-destination>
                <destination-name>
                patchbay:/sqldms/com/SystemBroker
                </destination-name>
                <destination-type>
                    Topic
                </destination-type>
            </input-destination>
        </input-port>
    </message-sink>
```

If any more information is needed, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Have you added your Message Sink (Broker) to the `Initial.properties` so that your service starts and listens for the messages in the production environment? Oracle documentation on this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Platform.10-2/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s0204startinganucleuscomponent01.html)

Comment: Hi @bated, yes it's been added in the initial properties

Comment: Suggest you have a look at document on [administering SQL JMS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Platform.10-2/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s1206usingthesqljmsadministrationinte01.html).  Should help you to debug the issue.